# How to scroll automatically in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, scroll, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Android I can scroll automatically at the end of my image:

```
scrollView.Post(() => scrollView.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Right));
```

How can I do the same in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ScrollView` has 2 methods available to accomplish this:

```
public Task ScrollToAsync (double x, double y, bool animated)
public Task ScrollToAsync (Element element, ScrollToPosition position, bool animated)
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView/#Public_Methods

Answer (score 3):

In a ListView you can use [ScrollTo](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ScrollTo(System.Object,Xamarin.Forms.ScrollToPosition,System.Boolean)/) , in  a ScrollView you can use [ScrollToAsync](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.ScrollToAsync(System.Double,System.Double,System.Boolean)/) for position or [ScrollToAsync for a element](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.ScrollToAsync(Xamarin.Forms.Element,Xamarin.Forms.ScrollToPosition,System.Boolean)/)

Comment: Could you come with an example of how to use this with binding and xaml?