# Xamarin Forms - point to label which became visible

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a feature in Xamarin Forms which will point to (scroll up) to a label which became visible after validation? What I am trying to do is: if required field is blank I display label under it - saying that it needs to be filled out, I have a scrollable page and when label becomes visible I want to make it show that label by scrolling the page to desired location, so user will know what is missing.
Thank you.

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401331/how-to-scroll-automatically-in-xamarin-forms/32404345#32404345)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **two distinct points** to implement:

- **first**, your entry validation: **there are many ways to do it**, but you can take a look at this fully documented sample from Xamarin: [Entry validation sample](https://blog.xamarin.com/validation-xamarin-forms-enterprise-apps/)
- **Then next**, you have to scroll to the (first) invalid entry control. That means that all your entries **must be embedded into a parent `Scrollview`** control. Then you have to find the first invalid UI element to scroll to (make your own "business" method to find this control).

Then just call the Scrollview scroll method. An example sample code could be:

```
// in your xaml.cs
//
public Task FocusInvalidEntryAsync()
{
    var firstInvalidEntry = FindInvalidEntries().FirstOrDefault();
    if(firstInvalidEntry != null)
    {
        return parentScrollView.ScrollToAsync(firstInvalidEntry, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
    }
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

The `FindInvalidEntries()` method is your own method to determine wich UI entry is invalid (maybe it needs your ViewModel).

Then `ScrolltoAsync()` is a method that will scroll the parent scrollview to the desired control. The last parameter indicates if you want to display the scroll animation.

Tell me if it's clear !